# How should I handle logging when I create libraries for others?

Tags: c#, logging

All. I am creating some libraries for other teams in my company. They all have different logging mechanisms. I want to provide trace information of what my libraries are doing. What should I to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: This might belong on stack overflow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the built in [`Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) mechanism and document the fact.

This way, all they need to do is configure tracing and they can log.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually suggest using the newer [TraceSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracesource?view=net-6.0) class, as recommended by the [BCL Team](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105043424/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396431.aspx) during early .NET 2.0 development.  This adds some additional bells and whistles like the ability to name sources independently of one another and handle configuration through app.config files.

Comment: Is it possible to put the configuration for TraceSource in a config file other than app.config file? Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that any of the .NET *.config files (app.config, machine.config, web.config, etc.) would do. Alternatively, you can configure the TraceSource objects entirely via code.  As a result, I suppose you could roll your own configuration system backed by a code library to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

[LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) lets your library dynamically attach to whatever logging framework is in use, without any additional dependencies.

It's often nicer than `Trace` etc. for a user, as they don't need to set anything additional up: if they're using a particular logging library, LibLog will detect it and everything will "just work".